# Hibernate throws a expecting OPEN, found '+'

Tags: java, hibernate

there is my hql below:

```
update User set count = count + ?2 where id = ?1
```

and there is exception details below:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found '+' near line 1, column 71 [update com.yitaosoft.edm.common.persist.entity.User set count = count + ? where id = ?]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
```

I want to update user set count = count + xx where id = xx. but got a syntax error. why ? is it not support in hql ?? how to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 9):

the problem is the fieldname count; it is a reserved word and should be quoted.
`Expected OPEN` means HQL parser is expecting `count(<expression>)` SQL expression and not `count = ...`.
The only solution is to alias `User` and force dotted fieldname as:

`update User u set u.count = (u.count + ?) where id = ?`

Answer (score 2):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update User set count = count + :count" +" where id = :Id");
query.setParameter("Id", id);
query.setParameter("count", count);
```

Comment: I am using a component written by me, it is a spring-jpa style liked component, but it only support placeholder now.                         @Query(value="update User set count = count + ?2 where id = ?1", writing=true)
 public void addCount(Long id, int count);