# unexpected token in select statement

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc app using hibernate and jpa, I am getting an unexpected token error when running the following query:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Description> findDescriptionsByConceptId(BigInteger id) {
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT desc FROM Description desc WHERE desc.concept.conceptPk.id =:cid");
    query.setParameter("cid", id);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:  
unexpected token: desc near line 1, column 8  
[SELECT desc FROM myapp.Description desc WHERE desc.concept.conceptPk.id =:cid]
```

How can I resolve this error message?  I would post more code, but I have no idea what is causing this error.

Comment: `desc` is a keyword in SQL.  You should surround it by escape characters (probably double quotes).  I have voted to close this question.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142224/hibernate-throws-a-expecting-open-found/22195932#22195932

Comment: He's using JPQL here, not SQL. 'desc' is a reserved word in JPQL also in this case, so you cannot use it in queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"desc" is commonly a reserved word, used in "order by" to represent descending value. Can you rename the column or surround it by quotes?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Description> findDescriptionsByConceptId(BigInteger id) {
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT tblDesc FROM Description tblDesc WHERE tblDesc.concept.conceptPk.id =:cid");
    query.setParameter("cid", id);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: with * not being a valid JPQL keyword?. I think not ;-)

Comment: _This worked for me..._ Have you _even_ tried your answer? Please read (eg. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html) before you post.

Comment: I put up a bounty on another hibernate question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454703/constraint-violation-when-persisting-one-to-many-relation